# Email api using react node nodemailer express is not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, axios, nodemailer

I am trying to create an contact page using ReactJs NodeJs express and nodemail. I am not getting any error. But it's not working. The post request is not working so i guess there's something wrong with the axios function but it could be anywhere else too so.Is the error in the backend part or the frontend part How do i fix it?

Post Log saying

```
Proxy error: Could not proxy request /api/forma from localhost:3000 to localhost:3001 (ECONNRESET)
```

**Client side**

```
import React,{useState} from 'react'
import axios from 'axios';


const Form = () => {
    const [name,setName] = useState("");
    const [email,setEmail] = useState("");
    const [message,setMessage] = useState("");
    const [sent,setSent] = useState(false);

    const formSubmit=(e)=> {
        e.preventDefault();

        let data = {
            name:name,
            email:email,
            message:message
        }

        axios.post('/api/forma',data)
        .then(res => {
            setSent(true);
        },resetForm())
        .catch(() => {
            console.log("message not sent");
        })

    }

    const resetForm = () => {
        setName("");
        setEmail("");
        setMessage("");
    
        setTimeout(()=> {
            setSent(false);
        },3000)  
    }

    

    return (
        <div className="container">
            <form onSubmit={formSubmit}>
                <div className="single">
                    <label>Name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="name" className="name" placeholder="Enter your name" 
                    value={name}
                    onChange={e => setName(e.target.value)}
                    />
                </div>
                <div className="single">
                    <label>Email</label>
                    <input type="text" name="email" className="email" placeholder="Enter your email"
                    value={email}
                    onChange={e => setEmail(e.target.value)}/>
                </div>

                <div className="textarea">
                    <label>Message</label>
                    <textarea name="message" id="" cols ="30" rows="5" placeholder="Enter your message here"
                    value={message}
                    onChange={e => setMessage(e.target.value)}></textarea>
                </div>

                <div className={sent?'msg msgAppear':'msg'}>
                    Message has been sent
                </div>

                <div>
                    <button type="submit">submit</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Form
```

**Server side**

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer')
const cors = require('cors')

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json);
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use(cors());

app.get('/',()=>{
    resizeBy.send("Welcome")
});

app.post('/api/forma',(req,res) => {
    let data = req.body
    let smtptransport = nodemailer.createTransport({
        service:'Gmail',
        port:465,
        auth:{
            user:'yourEmail@gmail.com',
            pass: "secreate"
        }
    });

    let  mailOptions = {
        from:data.email,
        to:'yourEmail@gmail.com',
        subject:`Message from ${data.name}`,
        html:`
        <h3>Informations<h3>
        <ul>
        <li>Name: ${data.name}</li>
        <li>Name: ${data.email}</li>
        </ul>

        <h3>Message<h3>
        <p>${data.message}</p>
        `

    }


    smtptransport.sendMail(mailOptions,(error,response) => {
        if(error){
            res.send(error)
        }
        else{
            res.send('Success')
        }
    })

    smtptransport.close();
})

    const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;

    app.listen(PORT,() => {
        console.log(`Server starting at port ${PORT}`);
    })
```

Comment: Can you share network logs from the dev tool? what you are getting for post request. As well as add quotes around the password while login in to the nodeMailer.

Comment: Yeah there's a POST request after i submitted the form and yes i added the quotes around the password too.

Comment: network log of POST /api/forma ?

Comment: This is probably not your problem, but your `.then()` handler is getting a second argument, and this is definitely wrong.

Comment: @PratikThube Proxy error: Could not proxy request /api/forma from localhost:3000 to http://localhost:3001 (ECONNRESET).

Comment: Also if you use gmail your from email address needs to also be gmail and match the username.

Comment: @Evert Yeah i removed that part. and yes the email address and the password are right.

Comment: change port number npm run build and restart

Comment: @DarshanMalani I changed it to 5000 but i am using concurrently to run both client and server side together  so i use npm run dev  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js",
    "server": "nodemon index.js",
    "client": "npm start --prefix client",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\""
  },

Comment: Just a heads-up if your backend is running on your local machine, it will not be able to send out the emails unless configured to. You need to run on a live server

Comment: can you make sure on which ports your client and backend service is running. one more thing can you add the backend  URL directly in the Axios call. meaning instead of axios.post('/api/forma',data) do Axios.post('/http://localhost:3001/api/forma',data)

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve this using gmail is creating a transporter.

Here is the working code:

***mail.service.js***

```
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'Gmail',
    auth: {
        user: '<myuser>@gmail.com',
        pass: '<mypassword>'
    },
    logger: false, // log to console
    debug: false // include SMTP traffic in the logs
});

exports.sendEmail = function(req, res) {
    const mailOptions = {
        from: '<myuser>@gmail.com',
        subject: 'My custom title ',
        text: 'Mensagem de: ' + req.body.nome + ', email: [' + req.body.email + '] ' + req.body.mensagem,
        to: req.body.email
    }
    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions).then((trans) => {
        res.status(200);
        res.json(trans);
        res.end();
    }).catch((error) => {
        res.status(500);
        res.json(error);
        res.end();
    });
}
```

Here is my router for sendemail action:

```
const router = require('express').Router();
const emailService = require('../services/mail.service.js');

router.post('/sendmail', emailService.sendEmail);

module.exports = router;
```

If you are in some situation of 403 errors you might need to do this [configurations steps provided by nodemailer](https://nodemailer.com/usage/using-gmail/) (this configuration is in gmail  account) .